# How to display with case sensitive in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am putting some values in datatable from an xml and I have values that repeat and also some values case sensitive

> ex: Cat,Elephant,Took,Program,Some,PROGRAM,Cat,Dog

so I am using one condition like

```
if (!(FindRow.Rows.Contains(val)))
{
   FindRow.Rows.Add(val);
}
```

I want my datatable to have both `Program` and `PROGRAM`, and should not have two cat values but its taking only one `program`

Comment: Does DataTable itself normalize case? Databases may depending (look into `COLLATION` configuration), but does DataTable?

Comment: just use FindRow.CaseSensitive = true;

Answer (score 1):

I can see at least two approaches:

1. Prepare `HashSet<string>` and every time you add item into `DataTable` add lowercased version of the same string into the set. Then every time you want to add new row check the set insteaf of the table.

   ```
   var set = new HashSet<string>();

   if (!(set.Contains(val.ToLower())))
   {
      FindRow.Rows.Add(val);
      set.Add(val.ToLower());
   }
   ```
2. You can use LINQ to perform a little more complicated query:

   ```
   if (!(FindRow.Rows.AsEnumerable().Any(r => r.Field<string>("YourKeyColumnName").ToLower() == val.ToLower())))
   {
      FindRow.Rows.Add(val);
   }
   ```

   You'll need `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` assemble referenced and `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions` at top of the file to make it work.